# Filling all available space by one of ScrollView's child views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my app, I have a `ScrollView` that has one static subview as a header and a `LazyVStack` with multiple elements that is filled with data from the view model. Additionally, if this "dynamic" data is empty, instead of the `LazyVStack`, I show a placeholder view. Here's a simplified structure of the view:

```swift
var body: some View {
  GeometryReader { geometry in
    ScrollView {
      HStack(spacing: .zero) {
        Text("This is my greeting to you")
        Spacer()
      }
      if greetings.isEmpty {
        PlaceholderView()
          .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
      } else {
        LazyVStack {
          ForEach(greetings, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
private var greetings: [String]
```

`PlaceholderView`:

```swift
VStack {
  Image(systemName: "hand.wave")
  Text("Hello world!")
}
```

I want `PlaceholderView` to be displayed in the middle of the available space (i.e., in this case, the entire screen height minus the height of the `HStack` on the top.) Many somewhat similar questions here suggest using `GeometryReader`, but it doesn't help in this case:

```swift
GeometryReader { geometry in
  ScrollView {
    HStack(spacing: .zero) {
      Text("This is my greetings to you")
      Spacer()
    }
    if greetings.isEmpty {
      ExampleView()
        .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
    } else {
      LazyVStack {
        ForEach(greetings, id: \.self) {
          Text($0)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the code above, `PlaceholderView` takes more space than needed. In my case, it should be something like `geometry.size.height - hStackHeight`:

[image]

Is there a way to make `PlaceholderView` take exactly the screen height minus `HStack`'s height? Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the placeholder to bounce up and down you can just avoid using a `ScrollView` in case there's no data to show. I mean:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State private var greetings = [String]()

    var body: some View {
        if greetings.isEmpty {
            VStack {
                header
                placeholder
            }
        } else {
            ScrollView {
                header
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(greetings, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private var placeholder: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "hand.wave")
            Text("Hello World")
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private var header: some View {
        HStack(spacing: .zero) {
            Text("This is my greeting to you")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the entire screen to be scrollable. That header ("This is my greeting to you") is just a simplification, in the real app there's much more.

Comment: But if I don't solve it for my initial requirements, I'll definitely go with this solution.

Comment: I decided to go with this solution. If "header + placeholder" don't fit the screen height, the initial requirement don't stand anyway. The layout described in the question is only possible when "header + placeholder" fit the screen and, thus, scrolling is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap `PlaceholderView` in a second `GeometryReader` then you can use it to get the vertical displacement in the global coordinate space (this being the `hStackHeight` you referred to). This can be subtracted from the height:

```swift
if greetings.isEmpty {
    GeometryReader { proxy2 in
        PlaceholderView()
            .frame(height: geometry.size.height
                   - proxy2.frame(in: .global).minY)
    }
} else {
```

[image: PlaceholderView]

The only thing with this solution is that the height grows when the message at the top is pushed away using a scroll action. This means the message and the placeholder don't move in sync, which seems a bit odd. So I would probably opt for suppressing the `ScrollView` when there are no greetings to display, as per the answer by superpuccio.

---

*EDIT* Finally worked it out. An additional `VStack` is necessary inside the `ScrollView`. Then the adjustment can use the coordinate space of the `VStack`. This resolves the issue of the non-synced scroll movement:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                HStack(spacing: .zero) {
                    Text("This is my greeting to you")
                    Spacer()
                }
                if greetings.isEmpty {
                    GeometryReader { proxy2 in
                        PlaceholderView()
                            .frame(height: geometry.size.height -
                                   proxy2.frame(in: .named("VStack")).minY
                            )
                    }
                } else {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(greetings, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "VStack")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for, but, unfortunately, I can't use it because of the issue you mentioned. I guess I need to fix `PlaceholderView`'s `frame` on the initial value somehow and block it from updating on scrolling, but I don't know how and whether it's possible.

Comment: (Upvoted because this is a useful hint, anyway, and might help others.)

Comment: Finally worked out a fix for the non-synced scroll movement. Answer updated.